# Как добавить новую вкладку с выводом taxonomy по определенному мета-полю?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, функции

Есть доска объявлений на **wordpress** с установленной темой **classipress**
На главной странице с объявлениями хочу добавить вкладку с новыми объявлениями вместо случайных и популярных у которого мета-поле (произвольное поле в объявлении) `cp_new`
[image: classipress]

Код табов главной страницы

```
<div class="tabcontrol">
  <?php $ad_tabs = cp_get_ads_listing_my_tabs(); ?>
  <ul class="tabnavig">
    <?php $tab_cnt = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ( $ad_tabs as $ad_tab => $ad_tab_args ) { ?>
    <li>
      <a href="#block<?php echo $tab_cnt++; ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $ad_tab ); ?>" <?php if ( 2 < $tab_cnt ) { echo ' class="dynamic-content"'; } ?>>
  <span class="big"><?php echo esc_html( $ad_tab_args['title'] ); ?></span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php $tab_cnt = 1; ?>
  <?php foreach ( $ad_tabs as $ad_tab => $ad_tab_args ) { ?>
  <!-- tab block -->
  <div id="block<?php echo $tab_cnt; ?>">
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <?php if ( 1 === $tab_cnt && function_exists( $ad_tab_args['callback'] ) ) {
    call_user_func( $ad_tab_args['callback'] );
    } else { ?>
    <div class="post-block-out post-block <?php echo esc_attr( $ad_tab ); ?>-placeholder">
      <!-- dynamically loaded content -->
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $tab_cnt++; ?>
  </div>
  <!-- /tab block -->
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- /tabcontrol -->
```

Для этого переопределяю и заменяю своей функцией **cp_get_ads_listing_my_tabs()** в **functions.php** дочерней темы и функцией *callbacka*. Вкладок таким образом становится 2 и они переключаются, но сам колбек не срабатывает - в него даже не заходит. Почему и как решить вопрос с работой вкладки?

```
function cp_get_ads_listing_my_tabs() {
  $defaults = array(
    'latest' => array(
      'title'    => 'Б/у запчасти',
      'callback' => 'cp_output_latest_ads_listing',
    ),
    'popular' => array(
      'title' => 'Новые запчасти',
      'callback' => 'cp_output_new_parts_listing',
    )
  );
  $tabs = apply_filters( 'cp_ads_listing_tabs', $defaults );
  return $tabs;
}

/**
 * Outputs a listing of new parts.
 *
 * 
 */
function cp_output_new_parts_listing() {
  global $wp_query; 
  remove_action( 'appthemes_after_endwhile', 'cp_do_pagination' );
  $post_type_url = add_query_arg( array( 'paged' => 2 ), get_post_type_archive_link( APP_POST_TYPE ) );
  // show all parts but make sure the sticky featured parts don't show up first
  $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
  query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'post_meta' => 'cp_new', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) );
  $total_pages = max( 1, absint( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) );
  get_template_part( 'loop', 'ad_listing' );
  if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
    cp_the_view_more_ads_link( $post_type_url );
  }
}
```

Comment: Для  начала гуглить почему не стоит использовать  `query_posts` и что когда нужно.

Comment: @SeVlad я читал, но в данном случае он встроен в тему и при стандартном отображении отрабатывает хорошо, поэтому не думаю, что как-то повлияет, если я по тем же принципам вместо случайных объявлений размещу свои с собственным мета-тегом.
вопрос в том, что колбек даже не пытается выполняться, если я в нем даже просто строчку с `echo` оставлю

Comment: Если он встроен в тему - тему нужно отправить в помойку. Тема древняя и дырявая. Я собсно к тому, что изменение на правильные методы изменит и вопрос. Может и сразу решит проблему. А заниматься неправильными.. Ну может кто и захочет, только зачем же публиковать опасные ответы.

Comment: @SeVlad может и так, но она выполняет свои функции. вы же ничего дельного конкретного и современного пока не предложили

Comment: Я-то предложил свершено конкретное.А если речь о неправильном и опасном тут да, я пас. Я предлагаю только правильные вещи. А тут мало того, что тема не из оф каталога. так ещё и такая... Разбираться с этим хламом нет никакого смысла.

Comment: @SeVlad единственное, что вы предложили - это "помойка" и "погуглить". Вы думаете, что если я во врех вопросах на форуме буду предлагать в ответах эти "конкретные вещи" - это кто-либо оценит и как-то решит вопрос?

Comment: Тебе потрындеть или решить? Вот если бы ты не огрызался а загуглил по данному ключу наверняка смог бы уже давно решить свой вопрос. Но хозяин барин. Жди блюдечка с цианидом.